# Joining computer to EC2 Active Directory With OpenVPN

Tags: active-directory, amazon-web-services, openvpn

I currently have 2 servers configured on AWS, one is a Windows server 2019 and another is an OpenVPN Access server, on the Windows server is configured a local active directory (company.local), and on the OpenVPN server is configured the VPN, the OpenVPN service is also connected with the AD, at this point is possible connect to the VPN through a domain user.

The problem is when I try to join a computer to the AD, because it does not resolve the name company.local (domain is not public), although if I ping the IP of the AD it works, but I don't know what else I should do to be able to join the computers to the domain.

I suppose that i have to do something with the DNS service, but i don't have idea.

Thank you for your time and ideas

Comment: You know the cause, you need to configure your host to use a DNS server that can resolve the domain.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, is there any way that I should not change the DNS of the computers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to configure the computer you want to join to the domain to use the Domain Controller for DNs so that it can resolve the name of the AD domain.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, is there any way that I should not change the DNS of the computers?

Comment: In order to join the domain, the computer needs to resolve the FQDN of the AD domain and query the DNS server of the AD domain for a Domain Controller. It does that by querying the DNS server that hosts the DNS zone for the AD domain.

Comment: Ok Joe, thank you i'm going to search about it